# Error in tapply(var, y, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : arguments must have same length

Tags: r

Why am I attaining this error? what does tapply mean? I haven't even used that method?

Error occurs: naive_model <-naiveBayes(X_train,Y_train)

Error:

```
Error in tapply(var, y, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

CODE:

```
  library(e1071)
  #Naive Bayes
  #Learn Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  naive_model <-naiveBayes(X_train,Y_train)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  naivebayes_Learnruntime[i]<- time.taken

  #Prediction Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  pred = predict(naive_model,X_test)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  naivebayes_Predictruntime [i]<- time.taken
```

[dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Balance+Scale)

entire code

```
balance_data = read.table(file.choose(), sep=",")
attach(balance_data)
x <- balance_data[, c(2,3,4,5)]
y <- balance_data[,1]
X_train <-head(x,500)
Y_train <- head(y,100)
X_test <-tail(x,122)
str(X_train)
str(X_test)
str(Y_train)


decisionTree_Learnruntime = c()
svm_Learnruntime = c()
naivebayes_Learnruntime = c()
knn_Learnruntime = c()

decisionTree_Predictruntime = c()
svm_Predictruntime = c()
naivebayes_Predictruntime =c()
knn_Predictruntime = c()


for (i in 1:20){
  library(e1071)
  library(caret)
  #SVM Model
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  svm_model <- svm(X_train,Y_train)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  svm_Learnruntime[i]<- time.taken

  #Prediction Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  pred <- predict(svm_model,X_test)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  svm_Predictruntime[i]<- time.taken

  library(rpart)
  #Decision Tree
  #Learn Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  tree_model <- rpart(X_train,Y_train)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  decisionTree_Learnruntime[i]<- time.taken

  #Prediction Time 
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  pred = predict(tree_model,X_test)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  decisionTree_Predictruntime[i] <- time.taken


  library(e1071)
  #Naive Bayes
  #Learn Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  naive_model <-naiveBayes(X_train,Y_train)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  naivebayes_Learnruntime[i]<- time.taken

  #Prediction Time
  start.time <- Sys.time()
  pred = predict(naive_model,X_test)
  end.time <- Sys.time()
  time.taken <- end.time - start.time
  naivebayes_Predictruntime [i]<- time.taken



}

svm_Learnruntime
svm_Predictruntime
decisionTree_Learnruntime
decisionTree_Predictruntime
naivebayes_Learnruntime
naivebayes_Predictruntime
```

Comment: First, it's important to indicate the line that is causing this error. Second, it would be helpful if you provide a working example data set where you get this result.

Comment: `tapply` is a base R function which possibly is used behind the scenes of one of the package functions like `naiveBayes()`. Check docs and be sure inputs are same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates a difference in lengths of your `naiveBayes()` inputs (`X_train` and `Y_train`) which need to be the same (i.e., a corresponding y value for every row of your x data). From

```
X_train <- head(x,500)
Y_train <- head(y,100)
```

we can see the inputs differ (1st 500 vs 1st 100 rows of `balance_data`).  Assigning the outcome data to `Y_train` from the corresponding rows of `X_train` will resolve this error message.  For example, you could use:

```
trainset <- 1:500  # to be similar to your 'head(x,500)'

# create train/test 
X_train <- balance_data[trainset, -1]  
Y_train <- balance_data[trainset, 1]   
X_test <- balance_data[-trainset, -1]   

# model and predict
naive_model <- naiveBayes(X_train, Y_train)
pred <- predict(naive_model, X_test)
```